# Design a search system based on two keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, tree, key

In an interview I was asked to design a system supporting "inserting/removing/search" for the data built from two keys:

```
k1(`float`) & k2(`uint`)
```

All the operations above (inserting/removing/search) are done based on `k1`. In addition they asked me to implement:

`bool search2(float k1_1,float k1_2)`

which returns true if there is an element with:

`k1_1<=k1<=k1_2 and k2 >= 100`

I proposed a binary search tree based on key `k1`; then `search2` is implemented by finding LCA (lowest common ancestor) for `k1_1 and k1_2`. and searching in the sub-tree rooted by the LCA for a node within `k2>=100`. So all operations take O(logn).

Is this a correct approach? Will be happy to hear your designs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like your solution will run in `O(log n)` for `search2`.  For example, if `k1_1` is the lowest value and `k1_2` is the largest, then your solution would require searching the whole tree for an entry with `k2>=100`.

Off the top of my head, what I would do is create two separate trees, one which contains entries with `k2<100` and the other with `k2>=100`.  Search would require searching both trees, but is still `O(log n)` because this is just a constant factor.  You could then implement `search2` in `O(log n)` by just searching the second tree.

Comment: LCA in a tree where each node has a pointer to its parent is `O(h)`, where `h` is the height of the tree.

Comment: Right, but searching the sub-tree rooted by the LCA for a node with k2>=100 is O(n).